# Can get id in Laravel 5.2

Tags: javascript, php, frameworks, laravel-5

I have problem, i can't get order_id.

In debug panel, I get this `<button class="btn btn-primary custom_button btn-sm" onclick="updateStatus(<?php echo e($order->order_id); ?>,0)">Inactive</button>`
In this, i can't get order_id.

My html code in blade:

```
<td>    
{!! $order->status=='0' ? 
        '<button class="btn btn-primary custom_button btn-sm" onClick="updateStatus({{$order->order_id}},0)">Inactive</button>' : 
        '<button class="btn btn-success custom_button btn-sm" onClick="updateStatus({{$order->order_id}},1)">Active</button>' !!}
</td>
```

My function javascript

```
function updateStatus($id,$status){
            var url='{{URL::to('admin/update_order')}}'+"/"+$id+"/"+$status;
            $.ajax({
                type:"post",
                url:url,
                data:"",
                success:function(response){
                    console.log(response);
                },error:function(){
                    console.log("fail");
                }
            })
        }
```

This is the result when print_r, because it so long, i put it in jsfiddle.
https://jsfiddle.net/aiduc/dkmocgnv/

How can I fix it?

Solved by @Navjot Singh

```
<td> {!! $order->status=='0' ? '<button class="btn btn-primary custom_button btn-sm" onClick="updateStatus(<?php echo $order->order_id;?>,0)">Inactive</button>' : '<button class="btn btn-success custom_button btn-sm" onClick="updateStatus(<?php echo $order->order_id;?>,1)">Active</button>' !!} </td>
```

Comment: Show your `updateStatus` function code here.

Comment: Hi @ChoncholMahmud my problem in the debug panel, it's showing me get id fail in it.

Comment: Print the $order to check the order_id is there or not

Comment: Hi @NavjotSingh, If i use if else statement , the order_id is there

Comment: what is the condition for which the order_id is there?

Comment: why do you use php tags ?? instead of `{{ $order->order_id }}`

Comment: hI @NavjotSingh, this is my html code, it's running exactly
`@if($order->status=='0')
<button id="btnStatus{{$order->order_id}}" class="btn btn-primary custom_button btn-sm" onClick="updateStatus({{$order->order_id}},1)">Chưa giao</button>
@else
<button id="btnStatus{{$order->order_id}}" class="btn btn-success custom_button btn-sm" onClick="updateStatus({{$order->order_id}},0)">Đã giao</button>
@endif`

Comment: Hi @Rodrane how to use it? please give me suggestion.

Comment: @John Can you please show the print_r($order);

or you can used the php like <?php echo  $order->order_id; ?>

Comment: <td>    
{!! $order->status=='0' ? 
        '<button class="btn btn-primary custom_button btn-sm" onClick="updateStatus(<?php echo $order->order_id;?>,0)">Inactive</button>' : 
        '<button class="btn btn-success custom_button btn-sm" onClick="updateStatus(<?php echo $order->order_id;?>,1)">Active</button>' !!}
</td>

Comment: and check your html of button that its have id in html or not

Comment: hi @NavjotSingh yes, it have id ;), thanks you so much

Comment: Paste it as answer  and accept so anyone else can get help